# Compiling Error 'undeclared identifier' C

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, doubly-linked-list

I'm almost finished with my code but it is giving me this error: '`curtemp: undeclared identifier`'. and '`prevtemp: undeclared identifier`' and '`missing ';' before type`' (last error is on the line of "float curtemp = current->temp;". I have no clue what's wrong with my code. I'm trying to remove some elements from a doubly linked list when the temperature inside that element is 5 more or  5 less than the temperature of the previous element.

Here's my .c file:

```
void remove_error(Dlist *list){

    DlistElmt *current;

    current = list->head; 
    //initializes ints for comparison
    float curtemp = current->temp;
    float prevtemp = current->temp;
    //now moves current to next data
    current = current -> next;

    //begins while loop for comparison of data
    while(current != NULL){
        curtemp = current -> temp;

        if((curtemp >= (prevtemp +5)) || (curtemp <= (prevtemp-5))){
            //removes current from the list
            dlist_remove(list, current);

            current = current->next;

        }
    }

 }
```

here's my struct element file:

```
typedef struct DlistElmt_ {

    int hour;
    int min;
    float temp;

    struct DlistElmt_ *prev;
    struct DlistElmt_ *next;

 } DlistElmt;
```

Comment: it used to be the case that C required all the variables to be defined at the top of the func, is this the case here?

Comment: You should paste your entire compilation error.

Comment: If you're compiling with MSVC in "C" mode (not C++), it requires the variables defined at the top.  And I agree with Frankie.

Answer (score 0):

With C89 or C90, it is expected that the variables must be declared at the beginning of a block (function or a local block). But, with C99, this restriction doesn't apply. So, in all probability, the suggestions of Karthik T & japreiss above must apply.

You can try by moving just the declaration of the float variables to the beginning of your function and assign them later on.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work because `current` is needed in the `curtemp` and `prevtemp` assignments.

Comment: My suggestion is similar to your code. I have suggested him to delcare it to the beginning of the function and assign the values later on.

Comment: @Gene: Of course it will work. You declare and/or initialize at the top, assign later on.  Don't you think that would have been a major oversight by the C standard committee?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not ISO standard C89, and I suspect you have a C89 compiler (like Visual C).   You'd have to recode some lines:

```
DlistElmt *current; 
float curtemp, prevtem;

current = list->head;  
//initializes ints for comparison 
curtemp = prevtemp = current->temp;
```

to make it so.

It is a `gcc` C89 extension, C99 standard, and also a C++ feature to allow declarations in the middle of blocks rather than only at the top.  This confuses many folks when they encounter a "pure" ISO C89 compiler.

It also looks like something's missing in your logic.  `prevtemp` is never updated once set.   If `prev` means previous, I'd guess you want inside the loop:

```
prevtem = curtemp;
curtemp = current -> temp;
```

In that case, some of your initialization steps are redundant.  Consider reading Gries on "The Science Of Programming" to learn how to avoid these kinds of bugs.

Comment: Gene, your information is two ISO standards out of date. C does permit mixed declarations and statements starting with the 1999 standard (and of course the 2011 standard retains this feature). Most C compilers support this feature; Microsoft's is a notable exception.

Comment: Thanks.  I should have said C89.   VC still doesnt' implement C99, e.g., and you need to say --std=c99 even with gcc.  I edited my answer.

Comment: Quibble: C89 was the ANSI standard; C90 was the equivalent ISO standard. Both ANSI and ISO consider all standards older than C11 to be obsolete. (C89/C90 is still commonly referred to as "ANSI C", though that's strictly incorrect.)

Answer (score 0):

MY guess is you are not including the file ***DlistElmt*** is defined, but you have included a declaration of DlistElmt so the compiler knows there is a DlistElmt things so you can use pointers to it, but when you try to do something with the contents of DlistElmt the compiler can't do anything with it.